# Creating Python Executables for *nix

Tags: python

I have written a library in python, that is kind of like a scripting language, and I had the idea of turning the library into a terminal executable that could be called like:

```
myprogram /path/to/file
```

So like python runs .py, this would run the file with the functions defined in my library. Is this at all possible?

Comment: Put `#!/usr/bin/python` as first line. THen `chmod +x myprogram.py`

Comment: that in no way answers the question. How can i make a program that runs the .whatever file with the defined function. Similar to a library but from the command line.

Comment: Aha! Sorry, misunderstood the question. So you need a dispatcher. YOu could make `executable.py` as I said and then make links to that in the form of `libfun1`, `lbfun2`, ... In the `executable.py` you make check over what is the zeroeth sys.argv, and based upon sys.argv[0] you dispatch to particular function

Comment: so basically a command line app that reads the file, and for each matching function in the file, runs that particular function?

Comment: @tristan no, he wants something like `busybox` as far as I understand

Comment: No, it is still unclear what you want, so let me write short answer and see if it is what you want

Comment: ok, yeah maybe i didnt ask the question the best..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose you write function like this

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import sys

if (sys.argv[0] == "./funA.py"):
    print("Calling A")
    # ...
    sys.exit(0)

if (sys.argv[0] == "./funB.py"):
    print("Calling B")
    # ...
    sys.exit(0)

print(sys.argv[0])
```

YOu call it `main.py`. Then you make links like this

```
$ `ln main.py funA.py`
$ `ln main.py funB.py`
```

It is really just one code, with three names and link count is equal to 3.
But if you run it

```
./funA.py
```

it will be dispatched to `funA` block in your code.
But if you run it

```
./funB.py
```

it will be dispatched to `funB` block in your code.
And so on and so forth

Is it what you're looking for?

Comment: yeah thats perfect!! thanks!

Comment: Glad to hear. This is how `busybox` for small systems works. It is all small unix functions utils like `ln`, `ls`, `cat` etc together. One executable linked statically, but then tons of links set from it to look like `ln`, `ls`, `cat`. And pretty much same dispatcher logic is selecting what function to run inside